# Python:I am untrying to untar a folder and would like to save only specific file to output folder.I am not getting the expected output

Tags: python

Below is the folder structure:

[image]

I have tried the below code to just save report`.json` into output directory and also I would like to rename it as same as `untar` filename that is `3884b56e33d16dd68faa4f1f25c28200.json`.

below is the code:

```
import tarfile
import os

outdir=os.mkdir("C:\\Users\\esrilka\\Documents\\Tar Files\\Untar Files3")
t = tarfile.open("C:\\Users\\esrilka\\Documents\\Tar Files\\3884b56e33d16dd68faa4f1f25c28200.tar.gz", 'r')
for member in t.getmembers():
    print(member)
    if "autodiscovery/report" in member.name:

        print("true")
        t.extract(member='autodiscovery\report.json',path='outdir')

print (os.listdir('outdir'))
```

How can I just save report`.json` into output directory and rename the file.

Comment: what kind of error are you getting, and in what line?

Comment: You can use a slash (`/`) instead of the escaped backslash (`\\`). Python will understand it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape a backslash literal with a backslash:

```
t.extract(member='autodiscovery\\report.json',path='outdir')
```

or you can use a raw string:

```
t.extract(member=r'autodiscovery\report.json',path='outdir')
```

But then since you have this condition:

```
if "autodiscovery/report" in member.name:
```

you should use a forward slash instead for extraction:

```
t.extract(member='autodiscovery/report.json',path='outdir')
```

Also, `os.mkdir` does not return the directory name it made, so your `outdir` variable would be `None`. You should assign the path name to `outdir` directly:

```
outdir="C:\\Users\\esrilka\\Documents\\Tar Files\\Untar Files3"
os.mkdir(outdir)
```

and then use it for `os.mkdir` and for extraction (note the lack of quotes around `outdir`):

```
t.extract(member='autodiscovery/report.json',path=outdir)
```

EDIT: Now that you mentioned that you want to extract `report.json` without the `autodiscovery` directory that is part of its path in the tar file, you would have to use the [`extractfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractfile) method instead and write the content to the desired location yourself:

```
with open(os.path.join(outdir, 'report.json'), 'w') as f:
    f.write(t.extractfile('autodiscovery/report.json').read())
```

If you want to rename `report.json` to the name of the tar file you can simply open the file different name:

```
with open(os.path.join(outdir, '3884b56e33d16dd68faa4f1f25c28200.json'), 'w') as f:
```

and if you want that name to be the same as the tar file, use `os.path.splitext` twice to obtain it (since there are two extension names, `.tar` and `.gz`, for your tar file), so that in the beginning you should do this:

```
archive = "C:\\Users\\esrilka\\Documents\\Tar Files\\3884b56e33d16dd68faa4f1f25c28200.tar.gz"
basename = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(archive)[0])[0])
t = tarfile.open(archive, 'r')
```

and then when you open the json file for writing:

```
with open(os.path.join(outdir, basename + '.json'), 'w') as f:
```

Comment: I tried with forward slash,but nothing is getting saved in outdir.Its empty

Comment: What's the output of your `print(member)`?

Comment: Just updated my answer to address another issue with your code.

Comment: Thanks now..i got the output in UNtar Files3\autodiscovery\report.json.But what i am trying to do is report.json file directly in untar files3.

Comment: Got it now...Thank you:) And is there any way that i can rename report .json to 3884b56e33d16dd68faa4f1f25c28200.json(with name of tar file)

Comment: I've updated my answer with instructions on how you can name the json file after the tar file.

Comment: I have tried with the basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(archive)[0])[0]...but it was only giving C:\Users\esrilka\Documents\Tar Files\3884b56e33d16dd68faa4f1f25c28200 for basename and not just 3884b56e33d16dd68faa4f1f25c28200

Comment: Indeed. I've updated my answer so that `basename = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(archive)[0])[0])` instead. Please try again.